# A variation of KnapSack

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

Consider the problem definition of a knapsack problem. Given a set S of objects - each having a profit and weight associated with it, I have to find a subset T of S, which gives me the maximum profit but has a total weight less than or equal to a constant W. Now consider an extra constraint. In the above problem the profit of one object is independent of another. Suppose I say they're interdependent, say I've a factor 0<= S_ij <=1 for two objects i and j. This factor diminishes the effect of the item with minimum profit. Effectively

`profit({i,j})=max(profit(i),profit(j))+S_ij * min(profit(i),profit(j))`

This keeps the effective sum between max(profit(i),profit(j)) and profit(i)+profit(j) -> "Atleast as good as the best one but not as good as using both simultaneously". Now I'm tyring to extend it for n>2. Is this a standard problem of some variation of knapsack ? Can I formulate an  LP(?) or NLP for this ?

**UPDATE:**

The set T is a strict subset of S. So you can only use objects in S(use duplicates if it exists in S).

As for the objective function, I'm still not sure about how to go about it. Above I've calculated the score for a 2 object sack considering the interactions between them. Now i want extend it over to more than 2 objects, and I'm not sure how to do it. The  letter 'n' is the size of sack. For n=2 I've defined a way of calculating the total profit of the sack but for n>2 I'm not quite clear.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise in your problem definition? Are you allowed to include multiple copies of an object (as you can in standard knapsack) or only one? Does the objective function sum the score (using the formula you provide) for all pairs of objects you have included? What do you mean "extend it for n > 2" (perhaps to n-tuples of objects?) Do you have an exact formulation of what you mean for the n-tuple case?

Comment: Also, I think it would be helpful if you included your attempts at formulating a mathematical program for this problem.